# Help to get my extension class working

Tags: apex, visualforce

The SOQL code works in a custom class but not in the extension class below .  I'd really appreciate any advice to resolve. I'm new to Apex.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as Anshul's change, having two references to the Contact list is likely to lead to trouble. If your page only references `ContactList`, the list will never be initialised as `getCustomers` won't be called. If your page references only `Customers` (so calling `getCustomers`) most code you add will work, but if `getCustomers` gets called later you will be completely replacing the Contact list which is probably not what you want. It's also best in code to not have two ways to do one thing.

There are various patterns that could be used instead - this is probably the simplest:

```
public with sharing class TableViewController {
    public Account acc {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}
    public TableViewController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        acc = (Account) sc.getRecord();
        contacts = [
                select Id, ...
                from Contact
                where AccountId = acc.Id
                order by Name
                limit 1000
                ];
    }
}
```

Your Visualforce then references the data via `{!acc}` and `{!contacts}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your getCustomers method has account's id harcoded in there. So, if you are expecting to see that your extension controller automatically retrieves records based on acccount id passed, then you'll have to modify your query to use account's id dynamically.

For e.g.

```
ConctactList = [select id, name ... from Account where id = :this.acc.id];
```